# Query relate to rf impedance matching

Tags: rf, impedance-matching, trace

I am into RF design and I have some queries related to impedance matching and trace. We had an RF module and the module was connected to an antenna through a single trace with  no LC components in between for additional matching.
But the trace width was set such that its characteristic impedance was set to 50 ohm. But in real time testing it was seen that the antenna feed impedance when measured from the RF module it was only 19 ohm, and after additional tuning I could achieve only up to 40 ohm.

Even thought the RF trace impedance was set to 50 ohm why did the impedance vary?

So is there any way in which the impedance can be improved by varying the RF trace impedance alone such that we can improve the 19 ohm to a value such that after additional tuning we can make it 50 ohm.

Also if we can set the trace impedance to the characteristic impedance why do we do we provide additional LC tuning and how is the matching done using the LC tuning?

Comment: What kind of antenna (Datasheet if applicable)? What frequency? And how long is the trace?

Comment: Actually i haven't used an antenna as such, a pad was given and i could get only 19 ohm for a frequency about 2 ghz just in the path from the module to the antenna pad. can the pad width to trace width ratio cause an impedance mismatch? because in some i have read and seen that in some places trace width will be almost equal to the pad width ,and somewhere else the trace width will be smaller but the impedance mismatch is nominal only. So does this have to do anything with antenna only because almost most losses occur at the antenna feed ryt? It would be kind if you could help

Comment: Were you measuring the trace looking in to the pad where the antenna would attach, or looking out from where the amplifier(?) drives the line? Was the amplifier still present when doing the measurement (are you sure you weren't just measuring the output impedance of the amplifier)? Was the amplifier powered up during the test?

Comment: A picture of how you connected your network analyzer to the circuit would probably help make clear what exactly you were measuring.

Comment: we where measuring the impedance at the antenna feed or antenna pad.

Comment: Was the driver amplifier connected to the other end of the trace? Was it powered up?

Comment: And when you say you did "additional tuning" what did you adjust to do that?

Comment: yes the driver amplifier was powered up. the additional tuning was to improve the mismatch by adding some discrete components (capacitance), such that the impedance improved but the maximum we could achieve was only like 38 ohm, so something we are missing.

Comment: This problem arises only as the frequency is getting higher, more mismatch is taking place at the high frequencies

Comment: How exactly did you measure the impedance? Did you use a time domain reflectometer or a VNA? In addition, you do not change the impedance of the TRANSMISSION LINE with discrete components, but with the transmission line geometries thereselves. Are you sure you understand the concept of characteristic impedance of a transmission line, because it is not something you can measure with a multimeter.

Comment: In addition, your transmission line should be more or less constant as a function of frequency. For example, If you're measuring 50ohms at 400 MHz, and  80 ohms at say 800 MHz, you are probably doing something wrong. Please be as thorough as possible with explaining what you did and i will be happy to help.

Comment: yeah i know that the impedance of a trace depends only on its geometry and it varies with frequencies.

Comment: yeah i know that the impedance of a trace depends only on its geometry and it varies with frequencies. In our case we had an  quectel EC 25 module whose 4G_ANT  pin was connected to a SMT antenna through a via. When we measured the path loss/trace loss of a single trace connecting both  (from the module side to the antenna side) through a VNA the impedance of the trace was 47 ohm at 700 Mhz, 27 ohm at 1500 Mhz and only 17 ohm at 2 Mhz. So something we feel has to taken in the layout side such as to minimize this impedance mismatch .

Comment: Also when i went through articles , it is said that the parasitic capacitance in a trace varies proportionally with frequency and it will be high at high frequencies if proper layout measures have not been taken care of. so can this  parasitic capacitance lead to an much more impedance mismatch? Also in certain designs The trace connecting the antenna feed to the receiver will have a much more width compared to other traces and should all the RF traces be rooted as co planar wave guides.